# O que é um Artefato de Software?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, terminologia

Em Engenharia de Software, muito ouve-se a respeito do termo Artefato de Software. Pesquisei a respeito e encontrei a seguinte definição:

> Um artefacto ou artefato é um dos vários tipos de subprodutos
> concretos produzido durante o desenvolvimento de software. Alguns
> artefatos (por exemplo, casos de uso, diagramas de classes e outros
> modelos UML, requisitos e documentos de projeto) ajudam a descrever a
> função, arquitetura e o design do software. Outros artefatos estão
> relacionados com o próprio processo de desenvolvimento - tais como
> planos de projetos, processos de negócios e avaliações de risco. Podem
> ser manuais, arquivos executáveis, módulos etc.
>
> O termo artefato em conexão com o desenvolvimento de software é
> amplamente associado com métodos ou processos de desenvolvimento
> específicos, por exemplo, o Processo Unificado. Este uso do termo pode
> ter sido originado com esses métodos.

[Fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artefato_(desenvolvimento_de_software)).

Ainda não consegui entender. O que é um Artefato de Software?

Comment: Na faculdade me disseram que um artefato era ou um documento ou um modelo. A diferença de um pro outro - caso não esteja claro - é que um documento tem a função primária de ser consultado por pessoas, enquanto um modelo em geral também recebe tratamento automatizado. Como tanto documentos quanto modelos precisam ser versionados, ir pra memória do projeto, etc, usou-se "artefato" para referir-se a ambos. Pelo menos foi assim que eu aprendi, não sei se é a forma como é usada atualmente.

Answer (score 2):

*<sup>O texto a seguir foi usado como fonte para o artigo da [Wikipédia Artefato (desenvolvimento de software)](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artefato_(desenvolvimento_de_software)) e não ao contrário vide o [histórico de revisões da Wikipédia](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Especial:MobileDiff/54717497).</sup>*

Quando se cria ou se mantém um software, vários documentos são criados no processo. Por exemplo:

- Casos de uso, para detalhar a interação do usuário com o software;
- Modelos de dados, para descrever como se estruturam os dados que o software usa;
- O próprio código-fonte do software;
- Diagramas UML de vários tipos;
- Atas ou outros registros de reuniões.

Esses documentos (e muitos outros) são necessários para que as pessoas envolvidas no desenvolvimento de software tenham uma base de informação em comum para se comunicar a respeito do software. Esses documentos são chamados, coletivamente, de artefatos de software. Dependendo da metodologia de desenvolvimento (se alguma for usada), os tipos de artefato variam.

É possível, em tese, não ter artefatos, exceto pelo código-fonte, mas isso vai tornar qualquer tarefa de manutenção do programa um pesadelo: para descobrir o que faz cada parte do sistema, seria preciso fazer engenharia reversa do programa! É muito mais prático consultar um diagrama ou documentação, e entender de cara como aquele pedaço do sistema funciona (ou deveria funcionar).

Comment: A edição da Wikipédia que incluiu o texto é de 5 de abril de 2019, conforme o histórico de edição do artigo:

https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Especial:MobileDiff/54717497

A minha resposta é de 23 de março de 2016. Portanto, foi a Wikipédia que copiou de mim, não o contrário. Sinto-me lisonjeado.

Comment: Desculpe minha falha. Vou deixar uma observação para que no futuro não cometam o mesmo equivoco.

Answer (score 2):

Estritamente falando um artefato é um subproduto concreto produzido durante o desenvolvimento de software. Porém o termo costuma ser usado principalmente na metodologia chamada [Unified Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Process). Claro que ele acabou sendo levado para outros usos no processo de desenvolvimento de software. Estes são os artefatos de gerenciamento de projetos.

Exemplo de artefatos são: casos de uso, diagramas de classes, tabelas e outros tipos que ajudam entender o software e requisitos e documentos de projeto. Nessa metodologia é sobre a documentação geral e não o software em si. Estes são os artefatos de documentação.

É comum o termo ser usado durante o *build* para referenciar ao objeto final criado nele. Em ferramentas de testes o termo também é usado como o executável e o conjunto de testes. É comum que estes testes envolvam *walkthroughs*, inspeções e provas de correção. Há casos que o termo é usado para o resultado final do software. Então o executável e os testes são artefatos. Estes são os artefatos de código, talvez o que o mgibsonbr chamou de modelo.

Há quem use o termo para qualquer atividade exercida e documentada durante o processo de desenvolvimento de software.

Existem usos até que não são diretamente ligados ao processo do desenvolvimento como de processamento de sinais, mas acho que não interessa tanto aqui.

Se formos usar o termo como na [definição da ciência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(error)), ele só deveria ser usado de forma específica em ambiente de testes.

O termo é importante em certos círculos, mas ele não é usado universalmente e em muitos lugares nunca o ouvirá. Ele não é intuitivo e sem ter uma definição clara e ver exemplos de uso a pessoa nem entende o que é. Ele é sobre ontologia e taxonomia, é um termo geral para algumas coisas, mas é mais específico que chamar apenas de "objetos".

Answer (score 1):

Entenda como artefato uma sub-parte do software. Pode ser desde a engenharia que resultou em uma parte ou artefato de software, até o código fonte que também compõem um o mesmo. Em outras palavras, é algo que compõe o ciclo de desenvolvimento do software que se inicia a análise, após o desenvolvimento seguido pelos testes e por ultimo a entrega do programa. Você pode pensar na construção de uma casa por exemplo, nela você tem vários artefatos que vão desde a elaboração do projeto até a construção e terminando com os acabamentos.

Essa é uma definição mais simples e resumida. Se você procurar na internet terá exemplos mais detalhados. Tentei falar de forma simples e objetiva, citando um exemplo do cotidiano.

Comment: Essa definição dá a entender que um artefato pode ser tanto concreto (um plano de projeto) como abstrato (a elaboração do projeto em si). Acredito que o termo artefato se aplica somente a elementos concretos, como é dito na definição incluída na pergunta. Pelo menos é como eu vejo o termo sendo usado.

Comment: A definição que coloquei é simples é objetiva. Voltando para área do software é algo que fica ainda mais complexo, aonde a definição de tal termo está ligada diretamente com o contexto. Entretanto concordo que um artefato é algo concreto. Por exemplo, uma rotina de teste que compõe parte do ciclo de desenvolvimento. Senão for gerada uma documentação não existe artefato. Contudo, o não existir artefato é a exceção (ou pelo menos deveria). Enfim, para chegar a uma definição exata seria necessário escrever um texto bem mais completo, mais para tal a internet está ai.

Answer (score 1):

Um artefato de software pode ser resumido como qualquer documento ou modelo gerado durante o desenvolvimento de um software. Para algumas pessoas, um pacote de software também pode ser considerado um artefato.

Eu pessoalmente sempre imagino um artefato como qualquer documento, seja ele físico ou digital, produzido durante o ciclo de vida do desenvolvimento de um software. Por exemplo, um documento de planejamento, um documento de requisitos, o backlog do produto, um diagrama de atividades, um guia de boas práticas, um documento de arquitetura, etc.