# O que são artefatos do design de software?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software

Estou estudando Design de Software através do SWEBOK e não consegui entender o que seriam os artefatos do design de software, como por exemplo em que tipo de documento seriam especificados os tipos de assuntos chave do design, como segurança, concorrência e internacionalização. Além disso, existe alguma ferramenta ou framework indicado para fazer esse tipo de documentação?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90308/101 parece responder melhor, se a resposta aqui fosse sobre isso a pergunta seria duplicata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o que você está procurando é uma forma de especificar requisitos, sejam eles funcionais ou não funcionais. Já que você está estudando por uma metodologia bem bem clássica, eu recomendo dar uma passada de olho no Enterprise Architect.

segurança, concorrência e internacionalização são geralmente classificados como requisitos não funcionais, mas ainda são requisitos, podem/devem estar ligados a diagramas e a testes.