# O que é o Native AOT?

Tags: .net

Anunciado com o .NET 7, toda a nova versão do Framework está sendo centralizada nisso, ou pelo menos as notícias estão. Achei que era a mesma coisa que o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30793/o-que-%C3%A9-net-native) mas aparentemente não é, no entanto, acho que [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30795/24529) não faz mais sentido para essa presente pergunta.

Fiz um teste com essa nova funcionalidade e gerei um executável independente do Framework e ele ficou com apenas 3MB de tamanho. Se fizer o mesmo procedimento com o .NET 6, ele ficará com mais de 50mb.

Por que isso aconteceu? O que é esse executável gerado e qual a diferença dele para os emitidos pelos seus predecessores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele é quase a mesma coisa que o .NET Native. É a união dele ao .NET normal (ou quase isso).

Em [O que é o MAUI da Microsoft?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455179/101) eu falo do termo One .NET (o termo que ouvi muito dentro da Microsoft quando ainda não podia ser divulgado publicamente). Esse é o nome original do .NET 5. [O projeto que "matou" o .NET Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

A ideia era que todos os .NET existentes se tornassem uma coisa só, não importava onde iria rodar e que modelo de execução e memória necessitasse.

Obviamente que isso não inclui versões muito especializadas (como o [.NET Micro Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/275588/101)), que praticamente era .NET só no nome, e convenhamos que já não é um [artefato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90308/101) de software necessário mais em quase cenário algum, e se for necessário a diferença é grande demais para conseguir inserir no mesmo *framework*. Note que é possível ter isso ainda, mas terá que fazer um *build* próprio do .NET. Tem quem já fez [jogo em aplicação com 8KB no .NET Native](https://github.com/MichalStrehovsky/SeeSharpSnake), já deve dar para algo próximo disso com o .NET 7.

De fato, o [Native AOT](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/NativeAOT?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é o novo nome do .NET Native. Que continua como um projeto experimental. Mas o termo também está sendo usado para o modo de geração da aplicação do .NET 7 que atende mais ou menos os mesmos objetivos. Não é exatamente a mesma coisa, mas é próximo.

Não considero que o .NET 7 está centralizado nisso, mas é a *feature* de maior destaque.

Então essa nova forma de gerar um executável é o que o .NET Native permitia com um *framework* alternativo, mas agora usa a mesma infraestrutura e todo o mesmo projeto/plataforma que você usa em tudo. Você escolhe qual modelo te atende melhor, se o que você usar na sua aplicação permitir fazer isso, não precisa escolher outro .NET.

Existem algumas limitações e na forma de gerar o executável em relação ao que o .NET fazia, mas é melhor assim. O .NET Native consegue ser mais agressivo, mas a Microsoft não conseguia manter dois projetos concorrentes. Por incrível que pareça o .NET Native era mais lento que o .NET comum, já que os esforços de otimização estavam no produto principal e não na alternativa nativa. Agora só tem um, todos esforços nele, e tem o melhor de cada um dos mundos (só tem que fazer a escolha).

Ele gera um executável nativo mesmo, esse que o sistema operacional roda de forma direta, igual ao que você produziria com C, C++, Rust, Delphi, Go, etc. E só vai o que realmente usa, fazendo um [*tree shaking*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/317837/101) bem agressivo (pode ser mais em futuras versões). Por isso dá para fazer executáveis com menos de 2MB (sim dá para deixar menor que seu teste) e dará melhor que isso. Só vai o que você usa de fato. E não tem dependências obrigatórias por causa do *runtime*.

Muito útil para rodar com [Blazor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101) por exemplo, onde tem que carregar a aplicação no navegador. Mas também é muito útil para rodar em *containers* e mesmo qualquer aplicação que precise ser distribuída. Também é útil para aplicações mobile com [Xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/xamarin?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Ter um *footprint* menor não é a única vantagem, ele pode ser mais rápido em certas situações. Certamente o *startup* da aplicação é muito reduzido porque ele não tem que fazer o [JITting](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) inicial porque o código nativo já foi gerado, e provavelmente de forma bem agressiva (poderá ser mais no futuro).

Então se não faz o JITting, não precisa ter o JITter, e isso por si só já diminui bem o tamanho do executável. Mais ainda, ele não precisa mandar o [CIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101), o que é uma vantagem. Na verdade, isso pode aumentar o tamanho do código porque o código nativo gasta mais espaço que o CIL. Mas há ganho quando mandava as duas opções ([ReadyToRun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ready-to-run?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

Obviamente que isso tem limitações, e não pode, ou não deve usar [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/506768/101). Isso é muito pesado, e no momento que usa se torna um enorme problema porque além de todo o mecanismo necessário, e dos [metadados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101) que precisam ir junto, o *tree shaking* não pode mais ser agressivo, ou nem pode ser feito, porque qualquer coisa pode ser chamada no código sem que o compilador saiba. Evitar a reflexão tradicional ajuda em outros ganhos.

Por isso que o .NET antes começou ter [geração de código](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), assim permite a reflexão em tempo de compilação, que é muito mais eficiente.

Um detalhe importante é que outras características continuam iguais, por exemplo a memória continua gerenciada e ele tem um [GC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255769/101) nesses 2/3MB (a ideia do Blazor é usar o GC do navegador quando isso estiver disponível no [WAsm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101), o que permitirá algo bem menor). Então não tem tanta magia assim, não está cortando na carne.

É claro que nem tudo é vantagem, além de inviabilizar reflexão em tempo de execução, não ter um JITter significa que não pode fazer otimizações em tempo de execução, então em alguns casos algumas execuções bem específicas podem ficar mais lentas que o modo original que permite [*tiered JITting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/compilation?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Se você pode pagar o preço de ter um trambolhão ou dependência, ou de demorar um pouco para iniciar a execução a aplicação, então pode ser que o modelo antigo te dê vantagens, pode continuar gerando o código assim. Vamos ver como se comporta na prática e como evolui nas próximas versões.

Com tudo isso o .NET fica competitivo com outras tecnologias para fazer quase qualquer tipo de aplicação. Então agora se você pode aceitar um GC e não precisa do máximo da performance em todos os pontos, C# pode ser competitivo (não igual) a usar C/C++ por exemplo.

Uma crítica que eu fazia ao .NET era ele ser um trambolhão que ou precisava de algo pré-instalado ou precisava mandar algo muito grande. Agora não mais.

[Documentação básica para iniciar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Ver mais sobre o modelo antigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/101). [Mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14334/101). [Mais ainda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).